# Uniqueness of the writing $f(x)=cx+p(x)$, $p$ periodic

Tags: real-analysis, functions, periodic-functions

Show that, if a function $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, defined as $f(x)=cx+p(x)$, is the sum of a "linear part" $x\mapsto cx$ and a "periodic part" $x\mapsto p(x)$, where $p$ is $\tau$-periodic, then that writing is unique, i.e. if $f(x)=mx+q(x)$, with $q$ $\mu$-periodic, then $p=q$ and $c=m$. Here $\tau,\mu>0$.

**What I have done**
It's easy to see that, for every $x\in\mathbb{R}$,$$p(x)-q(x)=(m-c)x \tag{1}$$
Furthermore, for every $n,r\in\mathbb{Z}$ we have
$$f(x+n\tau)=c(x+n\tau)+p(x) \tag{2}$$
$$f(x+r\mu)=m(x+r\mu)+q(x) \tag{3}$$
and therefore, (2)-(3) and (1) give, for every $x\in\mathbb{R}$ and $n,r\in\mathbb{Z}$
$$f(x+n\tau)-f(x+r\mu)=cn\tau-mr\mu\tag{4}$$

**Hypothesis: $\frac{\tau}{\mu} \in \mathbb{Q}$**
In this case there are $n',r'\in\mathbb{Z}-\{0\}$ such that $$n'\tau=r'\mu \tag{5}$$
therefore, from (4) and (5) we have
$$0=cn'\tau-mr'\mu=n'\tau(c-m)$$
so $c=m$ and, for (1), $p(x)=q(x)$ for every $x\in\mathbb{R}$.

**How can we proceed when $\frac{\tau}{\mu} \in \mathbb{R}-\mathbb{Q}$?**
This hypothesis must give a contradiction.

Any comments or answers will be appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: If $f$ is locally bounded, then $p$ is bounded so $c$ is the limit of $f(x)/x$ as $x \to \infty$. Uniqueness follows.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose $\tau/\mu$ is irrational.  Let $c,m$ be given real numbers.
We intend to construct $f$, $p$, and $q$ satisfying the conditions.  Of course $f,p,q$ are highly discontinuous.

Extend $\{\tau, \mu\}$ to
a Hamel basis of $\mathbb R$ over $\mathbb Q$.
That is, $\{\tau,\mu\}\cup B$ is a Hamel basis and $\{\tau,\mu\}\cap B = \varnothing$.

Define function $f : \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ in terms of that basis as follows:

Let $x \in \mathbb R$.  There exist unique coefficients
$x_\tau, x_\mu, (x_\beta)_{\beta \in B}$,
all but finitely many equal to zero, so that
$$
x = x_\tau \tau + x_\mu \mu +\sum_{\beta \in B} x_\beta \beta.
\tag1$$
Define
$$
f(x) := c x_\tau \tau + m x_\mu \mu.
\tag2$$  [So, defined in terms of a basis like this, $f$ is
a $\mathbb Q$-linear transformation of rank $2$.]

Define $p : \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ in terms of the basis:
For $x$ as in $(1)$, define
$$
p(x) := 0\,\tau + (m-c)x_\mu \mu - c \sum_{\beta \in B} x_\beta \beta.
\tag3$$
We claim $p$ has period $\tau$.  Indeed, if $x$ is as in $(1)$,
$$
x+\tau = (x_\tau+1)\tau+ x_\mu \mu +\sum_{\beta \in B} x_\beta \beta
\tag{1'}$$
so $p(x) = p(x+\tau)$.
Also note

$$
f(x) - p(x) = (c x_\tau)\tau + (m-(m-c))x_\mu\mu +c \sum_{\beta \in B} (x_\beta) \beta = c x .
\tag4$$

Similarly, define $q : \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ in terms of the basis:
For $x$ as in $(1)$, define
$$
q(x) = (c-m)x_\tau\tau + 0\,\mu - m\sum_{\beta\in B}x_\beta \beta
\tag5$$
As before: $q(x)$ has period $\mu$ and $f(x) -q(x) = mx$.

Comment: The existence of a Hamel basis is a consequence of the Zorn's Lemma, so, you have shown that, assuming it and $\tau, \mu$ are incommensurable, the writing $f(x)=cx+p(x)$ is not unique. However, the Zorn's Lemma is equivalent to the Axiom of Choice and it would be preferable not to use it. What can we demonstrate without AC?

Comment: @100nanoFarad ... NG's deleted answer shows it is unique provided certain sets are Lebegue measurable.  So in mere ZF you will never prove that it is not unique.

Comment: Ok, thank you anyway. Can we say that, in general and in ZF without AC, is not true that the writing is unique?

Comment: @100nanoFarad, I think this proof shows that in ZF, non-uniqueness could be either equivalent to the axiom of choice or true.